# Oracle XE stopped working. TNS listener refused connection

Tags: oracle11g, database-connection

I'm working on an application which uses Oracle XE 11g as its RDBMS. It was working for several weeks but now I started to get an error message about the connection being refused.

I restarted my system but it did not help. I uninstalled XE, deleted all remaining files (even from registry) and reinstalled it. Now I get another error message:

> Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12505,
>   TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect
>   descriptor

I've read about this error and others suggested adding a new SID to the listener.ora file:

```
(SID_DESC =
  (SID_NAME = XE)
  (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
)
```

If I do this I get another error message:

> ORA-01034: ORACLE not available ORA-27101: shared memory realm does
>   not exist

My configuration files are:
**listener.ora**

```
    SID_LIST_LISTENER =   (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = XE)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )   )

LISTENER =   (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = AAROLD.in.mycompany.com)(PORT = 1521))
    )   )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

**tnsnames.ora**

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = AAROLD.in.mycompany.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

**lsnrctl status** returns with:

```
LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 19-M┴RC. -2013 15:12:24

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                19-M┴RC. -2013 15:01:12
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 11 min. 11 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\AAROLD\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=AAROLD.in.mycompany.com)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Do you have any idea what can be the problem? I'm not an Oracle expert so I'm completely in the dark here.

Comment: Did you try starting your database?

Comment: Please search, "oracle xe start database" should lead you to promising information.

Comment: It does not help. I still get the same error message.

Comment: Rerun lsnrctl status to see if the db is registered.

Comment: I get exactly the same output as you can see in my post. What does that mean?

Comment: Means your database is either not started or not registering with the listener. Unless you've manually edited the listener configuration or the database configuration, the second option isn't likely.

Comment: I edited the configuration as I've said above. But it was not working in its original state either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Oracle DB is down. It may have some problem starting up.

Go to command prompt and type:

SQL>**sqlplus / as sysdba**

If you get a message "connected to an idle instance" then type

SQL>**startup**

and let me know the message you get. If you don't get the "connected to an idle instance" message on SqlPlus startup, the type:

SQL>**set lines 80 pages 50**

SQL>**select * from v$database;**

and post the output here.

Comment: I already tried that. The prompt starts but if I try to `connect` I get an error message about oracle not being able to check credentials. I **know** the password for the SYS and the SYSTEM user as well it just ain't working.

Answer (score 13):

I had the exact same problem and after spending almost 4 hours trying to find and answer, finally adding

```
(SID_DESC =
  (SID_NAME = XE)
  (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
)
```

to my listener.ora and restarting both XE services solved the issue. I am using 11.2.0 (XE) on windows 7 x64 with out any hitch till yesterday. A reboot of my PC this morning caused the listener to not find the SID.

Now I am backing up both listener.ora and tnsnames.ora.

btw, forgot to mention I changed the hostname in both the files from bob.mycompany.com to localhost.

Comment: Thank you! Now the second interesting part is why Oracle configurations spontaneously stop working..?

Comment: Yes, that would be interesting to know. My Oracle stopped working today and adding this to my listener.ora (and many starts and stops suggested in other helpful answers on this forum) fixed the problem. However, those lines were not necessary before. All that happened in between was a bluescreen fatal crash, which was most likely not related to Oracle.

Answer (score 12):

On Windows 7 64 bit, Orcale XE 11
my OracleXXETNSListener service was not running and did terminate immediately when I tried to start it.

1. Adding

> (SID_DESC =   (SID_NAME = XE)   (ORACLE_HOME =
>   C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server) )

to my

```
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN\listener.ora
```

2. changing the hostname to **localhost**
3. **restarting the OracleServiceXE service** under System - Services solved the issue.

So the complete **listener.ora** section looks like:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\servers\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\servers\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = XE)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\servers\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

Update:
Now it is 5 years later and I had the same issue with OracleXE 18c on Win10. The TNS listener would not start right after successful installation because *oracleXE\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora*
was pointing to localhost.docker.internal instead of localhost.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, and I fixed it by removing the "IPC" lines from both listener.ora and tnsnames.ora.

On `listener.ora`, I removed:

```
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
```

On `tnsnames.ora`, I removed:

```
EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

It may have been a overkill, but it's finally fixed, after several hours!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the error was I have changed the name of my machine  . This was solved by editing listener.ora and renaming the HOST:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostname_of_my_machine)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

Comment: would changing this to localhost as above mean renaming the machine will not break it again?