# Can't get Oracle TNS to work

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I have installed Oracle 11g on my Windows computer and can't get the TNS listener to work. when I run "lsnrctl start" I get:

```
> lsnrctl start
> LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on
> 17-APR-2017 17:59:51
> 
> Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
> 
> Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
> TNS-12541: TNS:no listener  TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error  
> TNS-00511: No listener    32-bit Windows Error: 2: No such file or
> directory Connecting to
> (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ASHWINPRAVE6F1E)(PORT=1521)))
> TNS-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
> TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error   TNS-00515: Connect failed
> because target host or object does not exist    32-bit Windows Error:
> 1001: Unknown error
```

Here are the listener.ora, sqlnet.ora, tnsnames.ora and log.xml files

listener.ora

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ASHWINPRAVE6F1E)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

tnsnames.ora

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ASHWINPRAVE6F1E)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

sqlnet.ora

```
# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to 
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native 
# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

log.xml

```
<msg time='2017-02-16T16:47:35.700-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 msg_id='dbgrmmdcrf_create_relation_full:1941:1503427940' type='NOTIFICATION' group='create'
 level='16' host_id='ASHWIN' host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'
 version='1'>
 <txt>Create Relation ADR_CONTROL
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-16T16:47:35.717-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 msg_id='dbgrmmdcrf_create_relation_full:1941:1503427940' type='NOTIFICATION' group='create'
 level='16' host_id='ASHWIN' host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Create Relation ADR_INVALIDATION
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-16T16:47:35.729-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 msg_id='dbgrmmdcrf_create_relation_full:1941:1503427940' type='NOTIFICATION' group='create'
 level='16' host_id='ASHWIN' host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Create Relation INC_METER_IMPT_DEF
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-16T16:47:35.750-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 msg_id='dbgrmmdcrf_create_relation_full:1941:1503427940' type='NOTIFICATION' group='create'
 level='16' host_id='ASHWIN' host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Create Relation INC_METER_PK_IMPTS
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-16T16:47:35.768-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>System parameter file is C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-16T16:47:35.768-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Log messages written to C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\Ashwin\listener\alert\log.xml
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-16T16:47:35.768-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Trace information written to C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\Ashwin\listener\trace\ora_2144_2656.trc
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-16T16:47:35.769-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Trace level is currently 0
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-16T16:47:35.770-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-16T16:47:35.771-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Started with pid=2144
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-16T16:47:35.783-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-16T16:47:38.514-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Error listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ASHWINPRAVE6F1E)(PORT=1521)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-16T16:47:38.514-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>TNS-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00515: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
   32-bit Windows Error: 1001: Unknown error
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-16T16:47:38.615-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>No longer listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-16T16:59:52.358-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>System parameter file is C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-16T16:59:52.362-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Log messages written to C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\Ashwin\listener\alert\log.xml
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-16T16:59:52.363-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Trace information written to C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\Ashwin\listener\trace\ora_2368_2864.trc
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-16T16:59:52.364-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Trace level is currently 0
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-16T16:59:52.369-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-16T16:59:52.373-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Started with pid=2368
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-16T16:59:52.381-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-16T16:59:54.313-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Error listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ASHWINPRAVE6F1E)(PORT=1521)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-16T16:59:54.315-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>TNS-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00515: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
   32-bit Windows Error: 1001: Unknown error
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-16T16:59:54.450-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>No longer listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-19T19:47:35.063-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>System parameter file is C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-19T19:47:35.077-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Log messages written to C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\Ashwin\listener\alert\log.xml
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-19T19:47:35.078-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Trace information written to C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\Ashwin\listener\trace\ora_2356_3004.trc
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-19T19:47:35.079-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Trace level is currently 0
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-19T19:47:35.079-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-19T19:47:35.081-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Started with pid=2356
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-19T19:47:35.088-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-19T19:47:36.913-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Error listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ASHWINPRAVE6F1E)(PORT=1521)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-19T19:47:36.913-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>TNS-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00515: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
   32-bit Windows Error: 1001: Unknown error
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-19T19:47:37.023-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>No longer listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-19T19:58:24.256-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>System parameter file is C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-19T19:58:24.265-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Log messages written to C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\Ashwin\listener\alert\log.xml
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-19T19:58:24.272-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Trace information written to C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\Ashwin\listener\trace\ora_2408_3072.trc
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-19T19:58:24.276-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Trace level is currently 0
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-19T19:58:24.281-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-19T19:58:24.287-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Started with pid=2408
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-19T19:58:24.318-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-19T19:58:26.605-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Error listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ASHWINPRAVE6F1E)(PORT=1521)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-19T19:58:26.607-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>TNS-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00515: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
   32-bit Windows Error: 1001: Unknown error
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-19T19:58:26.740-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>No longer listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-25T19:12:30.406-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>System parameter file is C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-25T19:12:30.411-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>Log messages written to C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\Ashwin\listener\alert\log.xml
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-25T19:12:30.412-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>Trace information written to C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\Ashwin\listener\trace\ora_2508_3080.trc
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-25T19:12:30.413-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>Trace level is currently 0
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-25T19:12:30.414-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-25T19:12:30.416-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>Started with pid=2508
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-25T19:12:30.424-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-25T19:12:32.732-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>Error listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ASHWINPRAVE6F1E)(PORT=1521)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-25T19:12:32.734-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>TNS-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00515: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
   32-bit Windows Error: 1001: Unknown error
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-25T19:12:32.854-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>No longer listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-28T19:13:29.576-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>System parameter file is C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-28T19:13:29.581-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Log messages written to C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\Ashwin\listener\alert\log.xml
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-28T19:13:29.592-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Trace information written to C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\Ashwin\listener\trace\ora_2392_2912.trc
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-28T19:13:29.593-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Trace level is currently 0
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-28T19:13:29.594-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-28T19:13:29.595-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Started with pid=2392
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-28T19:13:29.603-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-28T19:13:31.921-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>Error listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ASHWINPRAVE6F1E)(PORT=1521)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-28T19:13:31.921-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>TNS-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00515: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
   32-bit Windows Error: 1001: Unknown error
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-02-28T19:13:32.037-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%4'>
 <txt>No longer listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-03-11T22:33:40.338-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>System parameter file is C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-03-11T22:33:40.342-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>Log messages written to C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\Ashwin\listener\alert\log.xml
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-03-11T22:33:40.344-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>Trace information written to C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\Ashwin\listener\trace\ora_2376_2924.trc
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-03-11T22:33:40.345-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>Trace level is currently 0
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-03-11T22:33:40.346-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-03-11T22:33:40.873-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>Started with pid=2376
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-03-11T22:33:40.912-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-03-11T22:33:43.219-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>Error listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ASHWINPRAVE6F1E)(PORT=1521)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-03-11T22:33:43.219-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>TNS-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00515: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
   32-bit Windows Error: 1001: Unknown error
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-03-11T22:33:43.351-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>No longer listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-03-23T14:47:56.810-07:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>System parameter file is C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-03-23T14:47:56.815-07:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>Log messages written to C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\Ashwin\listener\alert\log.xml
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-03-23T14:47:56.817-07:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>Trace information written to C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\Ashwin\listener\trace\ora_2408_2844.trc
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-03-23T14:47:56.818-07:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>Trace level is currently 0
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-03-23T14:47:56.819-07:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-03-23T14:47:56.822-07:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>Started with pid=2408
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-03-23T14:47:56.829-07:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-03-23T14:47:59.128-07:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>Error listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ASHWINPRAVE6F1E)(PORT=1521)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-03-23T14:47:59.143-07:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>TNS-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00515: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
   32-bit Windows Error: 1001: Unknown error
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-03-23T14:47:59.259-07:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>No longer listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-03-23T15:04:20.534-07:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>System parameter file is C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2017-03-23T15:04:20.537-07:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='ASHWIN'
 host_addr='fe80::413b:ba3b:5867:6d82%5'>
 <txt>Log messages written to C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\Ashwin\listener\alert\log.xml
 </txt>
```

Can someone please help me to get this working? I have been trying for the last two days

EDIT:

I ran hostname on the command line, got the right hostname and changed it in the files with the field "HOST" to the proper hostname. It works now!

Comment: Does ASHWINPRAVE6F1E resolve to something?  ping ASHWINPRAVE6F1E

Comment: @BjarteBrandt I tried pinging it, I didn't get the proper response. I ran `hostname` on the command line, got the right hostname and changed it in the files with the field "HOST" to the proper hostname. It works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working flawlessly for over a year, my Oracle 11g stopped working today, exactly as described in this question here. In my case, adding the XE SID to listener.ora fixed the problem. Try this if the problem reappears some day:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = XE)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DEV-VM-RL.dev.local)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

[For more Information and other fixes, check out this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501832/oracle-xe-stopped-working-tns-listener-refused-connection)