# TimeoutException connecting to Oracle XE 11 via JDBC

Tags: jdbc, windows-10, ojdbc, oracle-xe

I am trying to coax Oracle XE into accepting connections from JDBC. I use ojdbc6.jar from the XE installation (there are the ojdbc5 and ojdbc6_g jars also). I have tried with oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver and oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver, the driver class is registered. I use the descriptor: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE.

I have also tried ending with /XE instead of :XE, which I have seen at times. Also tried actual hostname Kaveri instead of localhost.

I can log on with sqlplus, the database is open and the main service and TNS listener service are running.

listener.ora:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
(SID_LIST =
(SID_DESC =
  (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
  (ORACLE_HOME = E:\Data\OracleXE\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
  (PROGRAM = extproc)
)
(SID_DESC =
  (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
  (ORACLE_HOME = E:\Data\OracleXE\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
  (PROGRAM = extproc)
)
)

LISTENER =
(DESCRIPTION_LIST =
(DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Kaveri)(PORT = 1521))
)
)

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

tsnames.ora:

```
XE =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Kaveri)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
  (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
)
)

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS_LIST =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
)
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SID = PLSExtProc)
  (PRESENTATION = RO)
)
)

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
(DESCRIPTION = 
(ADDRESS_LIST = 
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
) 
(CONNECT_DATA = 
  (SID = CLRExtProc) 
  (PRESENTATION = RO) 
) 
)
```

I get

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.awaitConnection(OpenConnectionCommand.java:132)
at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.access$100(OpenConnectionCommand.java:45)
at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand$2.run(OpenConnectionCommand.java:115)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Alternatively using a java program of our own I get

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Socket read timed out
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:673)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:715)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:564)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
...
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Socket read timed out
at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:350)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolStream.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolStream.java:153)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:263)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1360)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:486)
... 39 more
```

lsnrctl seems to hang after a while:

```
> lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 04-JUL-2017 
17:29:09

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=Kaveri)(PORT=1521)))
```

This is a "fresh reinstallation" of Oracle XE on Windows 10. For the avoidance of doubt, I switched off firewall too, with no effect (I hope!).

How does one debug connecting to Oracle? Thank you.

UPDATE: I was lying - or Windows was - when it lists the TNSListener as running, the situation is actually "The OracleXETNSListener service on Local Computer started and then stopped..."

Answer (score 0):

If I use localhost instead of Kaveri in the configuration files, then the listener stays up (why, as the hostname is Kaveri..?)

After that [Bob 1174's answer here is what was needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19735405/848850).